# How to map two tables to populate one field value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-state

I have two schemas on the MongoDB. "Assign schema" which contains two fields user_story_id and user_id and another schema for User_story which contains the description of the user story. I want to create drop down within a form which will populate the assigned user stories. The assigned user story id can be obtained from the *Assign* schema and the User stories descriptions can be obtained from the User_story schema. So, I need both schemas for the implementation. Basically, we need to create a mapping between "Assign" and "User_story" schema.  I implemented it in React. The implementation code block is

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Task({}) {
  const [taskValues, setTaskValues] = useState({
    task: '',
    userStory: 'userStory1', // Default value
    createdBy: 'user1',       // Default value
    status: 'Pending',       // Default value
  });

  const [allTask, setAllTask] = useState([{}]);
  const [assigned, setAllAssign] = useState([{}]);
  const [allStories, setAllStories] = useState([{}]);

  const assignedUserStories = assigned.map((assigns) => {
    return assigns.user_story_id;
  })
  
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setTaskValues({ ...taskValues, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem('loggedInUser')
  const handleCreateTask = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const taskDetails = {
      task: taskValues.task,     //captured from input task
      user_story_id: taskValues.userStory,      //captured from dropdown
      status: taskValues.status,      //captured from status dropdown
      created_by: loggedInUser
    }

    // Post taskValues data to your server endpoint
    axios.post('http://localhost:9000/createTask', taskValues)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data) {
          alert('Task creation Successful');
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert('Error in creating the task');
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:9000/getTaskList')
      .then(function (response) {
        const Taskdata = response.data;
        setAllTask(Taskdata);
      });

    axios.get('http://localhost:9000/getUserstory')
      .then(function (response) {
        const Allstories = response.data;
        setAllStories(Allstories);
      });
  }, []);
 
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h2 className="card-title">Create a New Task</h2>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Task:</label>
                  <textarea
                    className="form-control"
                    name="task"
                    value={taskValues.task}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>User Story:</label>
                  <select
                    className="form-control"
                    name="userStory"
                    value={taskValues.userStory}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  >
                    {assignedUserStories.map((stories) =>
                      <option key={stories._id} value={stories._id}>{stories.user_story}</option>
                    
                    )}
                   
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Created by:</label>
                  <select
                    className="form-control"
                    name="createdBy"
                    value={taskValues.createdBy}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  >
                    <option value="user1">User 1</option>
                    <option value="user2">User 2</option>
                    <option value="user3">User 3</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Status:</label>
                  <select
                    className="form-control"
                    name="status"
                    value={taskValues.status}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  >
                    <option value="New">New</option>
                    <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                    <option value="Awaiting Confirmation">Awaiting Confirmation</option>
                    <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                    
                  </select>
                </div>

                      <button
                      onClick={() => handleCreateTask()}
                      className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                      >
                      Assign
                      </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, I am getting error while run the code block. The error is
[image]

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

It seems the issue is that you are attempting to map an array of undefined values that have no `_id` property.

```js
const [assigned, setAllAssign] = useState([{}]); // <-- empty object in array

...

const assignedUserStories = assigned.map((assigns) => {
  return assigns.user_story_id; // <-- undefined
})

...

{assignedUserStories.map((stories) => // <-- stories is undefined
  <option
    key={stories._id} // <-- can't access _id of undefined!
    value={stories._id}
  >
    {stories.user_story}
  </option>
)}
```

## Solution

I suggest not starting from invalid state, e.g. start from empty arrays instead of arrays with a single empty object reference. Rendering empty arrays is completely valid, and more importantly, safe, since you there will be (*presumably*) no invalid empty objects in the initial render cycle and until the `assigned` state is updated/populated on any subsequent render cycles.

```js
const [assigned, setAllAssign] = useState([]); // <-- empty array

...

const assignedUserStories = assigned.map((assigns) => { // <-- empty array
  return assigns.user_story_id;
})

...

{assignedUserStories.map((stories) => // <-- empty array
  <option
    key={stories._id}
    value={stories._id}
  >
    {stories.user_story}
  </option>
)}
```